# How to get maven and appengine to do hot reload when developing

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

I am trying to use the Java based appengine for a hobby project but I cannot get the hot reload/swap of my app to work when developing. I've tried several things but no luck.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <groupId>grocerymonkey</groupId>
  <artifactId>grocerymonkeyapp</artifactId>

  <properties>
    <!-- uncomment if you wish to set your project here project- gcloud is used otherwise -->
    <!-- <app.deploy.project>your-app-id</app.deploy.project> -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
  </properties>

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>3.5</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.59</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.59</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-tools-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.59</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.truth</groupId>
      <artifactId>truth</artifactId>
      <version>0.33</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
              <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api</exclude>
            <exclude>com.google.guava:guava</exclude> <!-- avoid android version -->
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-maven</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireMavenVersion>
                  <version>3.5</version>
                </requireMavenVersion>
                <requirePluginVersions>
                   <message>Best Practice is to always define plugin versions!</message>
                   <banLatest>true</banLatest>
                   <banRelease>true</banRelease>
                   <phases>clean,deploy,verify,appengine:run,appengine:deploy,appengine:update,appengine:devappaserver,site</phases>
                </requirePluginVersions>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

            <!-- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/building-app/environment-setup //-->
            <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
      </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.14.v20181114</version>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I cannot use mvh appengine:devserver, when I try I get the following error message

> Could not find goal 'devserver' in plugin
>   com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1 among available
>   goals deploy, deployCron, deployDispatch, deployDos, deployIndex,
>   deployQueue, genRepoInfoFile, help, run, stage, start, stop -> [Help
>   1]

I have tried setting fullscanseconds=5 and less but it doesn't matter if I change an HTML file or a servlet, I still have to stop the server and start it up again manually using mvn appengine:run. This makes it really, really time consuming to develop anything locally. I also tried using jetty, but this failed and then I realised appengine is apparently running on jetty when tested locally.

When I try to use jetty when developing I run into problems due to security constraints.

web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
            <web-resource-collection>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <user-data-constraint>
                <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
            </user-data-constraint>
        </security-constraint>
```

and jetty gives me a 403 error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You raised three different issues: hot reload on App Engine flexible, deployment issue when using mvh appengine:devserver and Jetty 403 error message.

Regarding hot reload, it is only possible in Java for certain cases, as explained by Patrice (googler) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25008594/how-to-auto-reload-app-engine-dev-server).

Regarding Jetty, 403 errors are mostly related to permissions, as described in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes):

> The request was valid, but the server is refusing action. The user
>   might not have the necessary permissions for a resource, or may need
>   an account of some sort.

Regarding mvn development environment, is difficult to evaluate based only on your `pom.xml` but based on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225782/mvn-appenginedevserver-error-could-not-find-goal-devserver-in-plugin-com-go), I would review the `groupIds`, the goals and parameters described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven-reference) (shouldn't you use appengine-web.xml instead of web.xml?) and the official documentation for [Apache Maven](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-maven).